# Create shortcode with parameter in PHP Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, shortcode

I've created a simple shortcode plugin on Joomla.
Actually I am trying to integrate Cleeng Video with Joomla. And will connect it's users in the future ( I hope ).
I've stack on creating shortcode's parameter. I don't know how to parse it's parameter and value.
My Shortcode is here (no parameter)

```
{cleengvideo}<iframe class="wistia_embed" src="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/5r8r9ib6di" name="wistia_embed" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>{/cleengvideo}
```

My code is here

```
public function onContentPrepare($content, $article, $params, $limit) {
     preg_match_all('/{cleengvideo}(.*?){\/cleengvideo}/is', $article->text, $matches);
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
      $videoCode = $matches[1][$i];
      $article->text = str_replace($match, $videoCode, $article->text);
      }
```

I want to set height, width and 5r8r9ib6di this code from shortcode at least.
Please can anyone help me with adding and parsing it's parameter

Answer (score 1):

To get a parameter, you can simply use the following code:

```
$params->get('param_name', 'default_value');
```

So for example, in your XML file, if you had a field like so:

```
<field name="width" type="text" label="Width" default="60px" />
```

you would call the parameter like so:

```
$params->get('width', '60px');
```

Note that you don't have to add the default value as the second string, however I always find it good practice.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but I need to make my shortcode with parameter.   For example my current shortcode is {cleengvideo}videourl{/cleengvideo}       and I would like to make it like this {cleengvideo width=150}videourl{/cleengvideo}   Sorry for my bad description and bad english

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. Try this: `preg_match_all('/{cleengvideo width="' . $params->get('width') . '"}(.*?){\/cleengvideo}/is', $article->text, $matches);` then call the width parameter in your `<iframe>` tag

Comment: Thank you again, I am sorry for made you misunderstood. I should pick an another example. Adding joomla plugin's parameter having no problem. I am trying to parse the Shortcode's parameter. I mean fetch OfferID from this code {cleengvideo offerid="R575665444_MN"}  . But when I comes to " preg_match_all " and foreach loop, I got lost. Preg_match_all is on my first post. Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

I think I could found it's solution.
It's here https://github.com/Cleeng/cleeng-wp-plugin/blob/master/php/classes/Frontend.php
Code is

```
$expr = '/\[cleeng_content(.*?[^\\\])\](.*?[^\\\])\[\/cleeng_content\]/is';
        preg_match_all( $expr, $post->post_content, $m );
        foreach ( $m[0] as $key => $content ) {
            $paramLine = $m[1][$key];
            $expr = '/(\w+)\s*=\s*(?:\"|&quot;)(.*?)(?<!\\\)(?:\"|&quot;)/si';
            preg_match_all( $expr, $paramLine, $mm );

            if ( ! isset( $mm[0] ) || ! count( $mm[0] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            $params = array( );
            foreach ( $mm[1] as $key => $paramName ) {
                $params[$paramName] = $mm[2][$key];
            }
            if ( ! isset( $params['id'] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            $content = array(
                'contentId' => $params['id'],
                'shortDescription' => @$params['description'],
                'price' => @$params['price'],
                'itemType' => 'article',
                'purchased' => false,
                'shortUrl' => '',
                'referred' => false,
                'referralProgramEnabled' => false,
                'referralRate' => 0,
                'rated' => false,
                'publisherId' => '000000000',
                'publisherName' => '',
                'averageRating' => 4,
                'canVote' => false,
                'currencySymbol' => '',
                'sync' => false
            );

            if ( isset( $params['referral'] ) ) {
                $content['referralProgramEnabled'] = true;
                $content['referralRate'] = $params['referral'];
            }

            if ( isset( $params['ls'] ) && isset( $params['le'] ) ) {
                $content['hasLayerDates'] = true;
                $content['layerStartDate'] = $params['ls'];
                $content['layerEndDate'] = $params['le'];
            }

            $this->cleeng_content[$params['id']] = $content;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone searching for shortcode parameters, for parameters in short code we can use preg_match_all like that

```
preg_match_all('/{cleengvideo(.*?)}(.*?){\/cleengvideo}/is', $article->text, $matches);
```

This will give a array with 3 array elements, the second array have the parameters which you can maupulate with codes.

Hope this helps.